# python Catching several errors at once

Tags: python

I am trying to do this Python error handling task and I did all I can but it is not printing what it is supposed to. Can anybody help me determine what I am missing? Thank you so much!

**Assignment:**
This exercise combines several normal error scenarios into one program. In this exercise, create a program which prompts the user for a file name. Based on user input, open the given file and read the contents into one big string. Then convert this string to an integer and divides the number 1000 with the number. Finally, print out the result from the division.

The idea here is that no matter what the user input is, the program works. If the file cannot be found, the program prints "There seems to be no file with that name.". If the conversion fails, print "The file contents are unsuitable.", in other errors, print "There was a problem with the program.", or if everything went correctly, print "The result was [result].". In any case (besides `KeyboardInterruption` with <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd>), the program should be impossible to break with user input. If everything works as intended, it prints the following output:

```
>>> 

Give the file name: hahaha...NO

There seems to be no file with that name.

>>> 

Give the file name: notebook.txt

The file contents were unsuitable.

>>> 



Give the file name: number.txt

The result was 3.194888178913738

>>>
```

**My code**:

```
def getfilename():
      filename = input("Give the file name: ")
      return filename

def main():
      returned=getfilename()
      
      try:
          handle = open(returned,"r")
          filetext = handle.read()
          result=int(1000/filetext)
      except IOError:
          print ("There seems to be no file with that name.")
      except (TypeError, ValueError):
          print ("The file contents were unsuitable.")
      else:
          print ("The result was",result)
if __name__ == "__main__":
     getfilename()
```

**My code's output**

```
Give the file name: hahaha...NO
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're calling `getfilename` in your `__main__` block when you really want to call `main`.

To avoid the subsequent `TypeError` you're receiving, you'll want to coerce `filetext` into a number *before* using it in your division. Given your expected output is:

```
"The result was 3.194888178913738"
```

...you probably mean to make it a `float` rather than an `int`:

```
result = 1000 / float(filetext)
```

Comment: oh thanks, I didn't see that but still the else statement is not printing the output "The result was 3.194888178913738" Instead it is printing "The file contents were unsuitable."

Comment: Updated the answer. See above.

Answer (score 0):

```py
 filename = input("Give the file name: ")
    try:
        file = open(filename, "r")
        data = file.read().replace('\n', '')
        divider = int(data)
        result = 1000 / divider
        file.close()
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("There seems to be no file with that name.")
    except (TypeError, ValueError):
        print("The file contents were unsuitable.")
    except Exception:
        print("There was a problem with the program.")
    else:
        print("The result was", result)
```

Comment: An answer that is only code is not very helpful. I suggest you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75843287/edit) your post to include an explanation.